# How do I find the version of Oracle JET cli currently installed on my machine?

Tags: command-line-interface, oracle-jet

In previous libraries that I worked with we could find the version with `-v` or `-version`. But in ojet-cli it simply shows the list of available commands, out of which version isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked their [github page](https://github.com/oracle/ojet-cli) and [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet400/jet/developer/GUID-ABE2373F-287F-4C3A-BEBD-02F179F399FD.htm#GUID-8A2D524A-3822-4D5D-8E87-1E1B39283999), and you're right, it isn't obvious how to find the version. You have to use double hyphens:

```
ojet --version
```